# Show all layers stocked on a GeoServer workspace in a LayerTree (Openlayers3/ExtJS6/GeoExt3)

Tags: geoserver, geoext, ext-js

I'm building a layer tree and I would like it to be updated automatically when the page is loaded with layer that are in a specific workspace on GeoServer.

In my layer tree I have a group containing background layers such as Bing satellite and OSM, and another group that will contain the GeoServer layers.

How can I request the layers from the workspace and add them automatically?

Comment: look at the getCapabilities response and parse it into a list

Comment: I'm not sure how to retrieve what I get in the XML file and transform it into a layer list callable by Openlayers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have that (yet) on GeoExt 3. Meanwhile, you might check another smaller project focused on managing layers, called extjs_ol3_layercontrol. It is also written in ExtJS.

Check the [blog](http://freeopengis.blogspot.pt/2015/11/openlayers-3-layer-control-extjs.html) and the [github](https://github.com/ptsagkis/extjs_ol3_layercontrol).

If you add the Geoserver capabilities URL (something like http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.3&request=GetCapabilities) to `ol.control.LayerControl` you can add your layers from it.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing this. I am working on extjs 6 and Geoext 3 but my layer tree couldn't show in mvc sencha app. When I looked at the openlayers tool, I couldn't find any information on how to use it on ExtJs 6. Is it possible to use it for extjs 6?